# How to Prevent Reuse of Deleted Primary Key Values in Table?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table with the primary key set to auto increment.  Sometimes, records get deleted. When this happens, I DO NOT want to reuse the deleted 'recID' values ... but that's what happens!

For example, ***in the table definition exported by phpMyAdmin below***, the table should start numbering at 19 but it shows 13.

How can I prevent the re-use of deleted primary key values?

```
CREATE TABLE scans (
  recID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  mac varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE scans
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (recID);

ALTER TABLE scans
  MODIFY recID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
```

Comment: ..., AUTO_INCREMENT=19;
- You're telling mysql to start at 13... change it to 19, or rather, remove that part completely.

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon   I would guess the Code-block above is actually generated by mysql when dumping the table-structure. Because MySQL behaves that way in certain conditions. It's _really_ irritating!

Comment: o_O yuo set `AUTO_INCREMENT` explicitly !!! When you do this the AI value is set to `greatest(specified, greatest existing)`. Remove AI specifying from last ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how was that exported table definition produced? What tool did you use to export it?

Comment: I exported it out of phpMyAdmin

Comment: Considdering Bill's comment below... which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only foolproof solution is to not delete the rows. Or at least don't delete the row with the highest auto-increment value.

Comment: Might be good to mention why...    that the auto-inc in some situations recalculates itself to the lowest number not used in the table. It's a long time since I had it happen to me but I think one such situation is when restarting the daemon?

Comment: Yes, in older versions. But in MySQL 8.0, a table's auto-inc value is persistent, so that case no longer happens. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-initialization

Comment: But if you don't delete the rows, then even an ALTER TABLE that tries to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT value for a table cannot set it to a value less than the current max in the table, plus one.

Comment: Thanks, Bill (and Samuel).  Sounds obvious when you say it :-)